# How to implement a side navigation with sub-menus in angular?

Tags: angular

I am implementing a side navigation using Angular.My requirement is that when i click on one the items,the sub items under that should render.

```
<div>
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let page of pages">
          <button mat-icon-button id="{{page.id}}"  (click)="rightNavOpen(true,page?.name)">
          <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;"></mat-icon>
          <span id="shapeName" [@animateText]="linkText ? 'show' : 'hide'">{{ page?.name }} </span></button>
        </a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </div>
```

The value of the page.name is being rendered on the sidenavigation.I want to insert a sub menu under it.How can I do it?